Print Cumulative column values in Oracle SQL
I have the following data set:
A 1 
B 2 
C 3 
D 4 

1)I need to print as follows:
A 1 A1
B 2 A1,B2
C 3 A1,B2,C3
D 4 A1,B2,C3,D4

2)I also need to print as follows:
A 1 A1,B2,C3,D4
B 2 A1,B2,C3,D4
C 3 A1,B2,C3,D4
D 4 A1,B2,C3,D4

Is it possible to do this in SQL?

"Is it possible to do this in SQL?" Yes, it is. What have you tried? What were the issues/errors with your attempt.

I don't know anything about SQL. So nothing has been tried. Does that help?

The way you have asked your question suggests it's a homework exercise, and there are specific guidelines for those. That may not be the case but it is what it looks like. As that FAQ mentions "Users here respond negatively if your question gives them the impression that you're asking them to do your work for you." Which may be unfair, but that's what happens. You have also left out details like how the data should be ordered - we might assume by the first column, but could be either, and there could be duplicates, etc.

Oh, so that's why people downgraded this question? That they thought this was homework?? Thanks for clarifying it. Well, I work as an AVP with a pretty reputed firm, with 30+ years of industry exposure. But I do get to work from home. So you can say it is home work :)

Since this appears to be a homework question.

You can concatenate string values using the || operator.

You can aggregate strings using the LISTAGG function
LISTAGG(value, separator) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY something)


You can apply an aggregation function to the entire range by converting it to an analytic function, for LISTAGG this would be:
LISTAGG(value, separator) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY something) OVER()

To get your second result, you can concatenate the columns and then use the LISTAGG analytic function over the entire range window to aggregate the values.

If you want a running aggregation, typically you would add an ORDER BY clause to the analytic function. For example, using SUM to get cumulative totals:
SUM(value) OVER(ORDER BY something)

However, while the analytic version of LISTAGG supports aggregating over the entire range window, it does not support running aggregations so you will have to use a different technique.

To get the first solution, you can use a correlated sub-query and aggregation:
SELECT t.*,
       ( SELECT <perform the aggregation here>
         FROM   table_name l
         WHERE  t.something <= l.something
       ) AS running_total
FROM   table_name t



Combining these parts is left as an exercise to the reader so that they can get the full learning benefit from their homework.

with data(id, k, v ) as (
    select 1, 'A', 1 union all 
    select 2, 'B', 2 union all 
    select 3, 'C', 3 union all 
    select 4, 'D', 4 
),
cte(id, k, v, kv) as (
    select id, k, v, k || v as kv 
    from data where id = 1
    
    union all
    
    select d.id, d.k, d.v, c.kv || ',' || d.k || d.v
    from cte c
    join data d on d.id = c.id + 1
)
select k, v, kv from cte
union all
select c.k, c.v, l.kv
from (
    select row_number() over(order by id desc) as rn, kv from cte
) l
cross apply cte c 
where l.rn = 1
;

A   1   A1
B   2   A1,B2
C   3   A1,B2,C3
D   4   A1,B2,C3,D4
A   1   A1,B2,C3,D4
B   2   A1,B2,C3,D4
C   3   A1,B2,C3,D4
D   4   A1,B2,C3,D4


Beautiful answer, works right out of the box for SQL Server! Thanks a lot p3consulting, appreciate it! For folks looking for Oracle solution, please add "from dual" where is data set is defined.

I wrote it with ORACLE but version 23ai where "from dual" is no more needed...

Ah, I didn't know that. Thanks for pointing it out.
